# How to merge this data.frames with common columns?

Tags: r

I'd like to merge two data.frames to get this result but I don't know how to deal with common columns...
Any idea ?
Thanks

```r
df_stock <- data.frame(
  CODE_S = c("57210390", "33210390"),
  `2023-04-01` = c(1.1, 1.5),
  `2023-11-01` = c(3.1, 4.2),
  check.names = FALSE)

df_flux <- data.frame(
  CODE_S = c("57210390"), 
  `2023-10-01` = c(1.25), 
  `2023-11-01` = c(1.31),
  check.names = FALSE)

expected_result <- data.frame(
  CODE_S = c("57210390", "33210390"),
  `2023-04-01` = c(1.1, 1.5),
  `2023-10-01` = c(1.25,NA),
  `2023-11-01` = c(1.31, 4.2),
  check.names = FALSE)
```

This is how data.frames looks like :

```r
> df_stock
    CODE_S 2023-04-01 2023-11-01
1 57210390        1.1        3.1
2 33210390        1.5        4.2

> df_flux
    CODE_S 2023-10-01 2023-11-01
1 57210390       1.25       1.31

> expected_result
    CODE_S 2023-04-01 2023-10-01 2023-11-01
1 57210390        1.1       1.25       1.31
2 33210390        1.5         NA       4.20
```

Comment: yes it's because I want to update the value `3.1` for CODE_S=57210390 and 2023-11-01 with the new value 1.31 from `df_flux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a merge/join with some coalescing.

## base R

This does not preserve sort.

```r
out <- merge(df_stock, df_flux, by = "CODE_S", all = TRUE, suffix = c("", ".y"))
ys <- grep("\\.y$", names(out), value = TRUE)
xs <- sub("\\.y$", "", ys)
out[,xs] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(y), x, y), out[,xs,drop=FALSE], out[,ys,drop=FALSE])
out[,ys] <- NULL
out
#     CODE_S 2023-04-01 2023-11-01 2023-10-01
# 1 33210390        1.5       4.20         NA
# 2 57210390        1.1       1.31       1.25
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df_stock, df_flux, by = "CODE_S") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ coalesce(pick(sub("\\.x$", ".y", cur_column()))[[1]], .))) %>%
  select(-ends_with("y")) %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~ sub("\\.x$", "", .))
#     CODE_S 2023-04-01 2023-11-01 2023-10-01
# 1 57210390        1.1       1.31       1.25
# 2 33210390        1.5       4.20         NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot r2evans ! FYI I have this warning : ! `cur_data()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0. ℹ Please use `pick()` instead.

Comment: Do you have any idea to correct code with `pick()` instead ?

Comment: It's just to avoid the warning message

Comment: See my edit, it should be fine

Comment: Yes, this is awesome !

Answer (score 1):

This merge keeps the latest variable for each observation, so the input order affects the result, right? With this in mind, here´s my `dplyr` take, using `pivot_longer`/`pivot_wider` instead of `coalesce` and sorting the columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # To sort columns

# ---------------------------------------    
df_merge <- bind_rows(df_stock, df_flux)

df_merge <- pivot_longer(
  df_merge, cols = -CODE_S, 
  names_to = "date", values_to = "value", 
  values_drop_na = TRUE) 

df_merge <- slice_tail(df_merge, by = c(CODE_S, date), n = 1)
df_merge <- pivot_wider(df_merge, names_from = "date", values_from = "value")

aux_columns <- as.character(sort(lubridate::ymd(colnames(df_merge[, -1]))))
df_merge <- select(df_merge, CODE_S, all_of(aux_columns))

rm(aux_columns)

# ---------------------------------------
df_merge

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  CODE_S   `2023-04-01` `2023-10-01` `2023-11-01`
  <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 57210390          1.1         1.25         1.31
2 33210390          1.5        NA            4.2
```